# How to implement a SAML 2.0 authentication into a JavaScript SPA WebApp login form?

Tags: javascript, azure, sap, saml-2.0, restful-authentication

Working with enterprise cloud systems such as Azure and SCP (SAP Cloud Platform) requires knowing how to exploit and implement SSO (Single Sign-On) authentication. Both cloud systems adopt SAML 2.0 protocol to implement SSO, which is quite easy to configure. However, it is not clear to me how to use this protocol into a JavaScript SPA WebApp to implement the login form. Azure provides the following APIs.
[image]

Which is the way to call these APIs? There is a [good introductive documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-saml-protocol-reference) provided by Azure, but from the development point of view I cannot find any actual usage example. Is it necessary to use a library? Which one? Maybe I have misunderstood the aim of SAML and I should use a different authentication protocol such as OAuth 2.0. Is that right?

Comment: As you can see, Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) uses the SAML 2.0 protocol to enable applications to provide a single sign-on experience to their users. For using AAD with your scenario, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp/).

Comment: did you ever get a soln for this?

Answer (score 0):

I this is a very old question but the answer hasn't changed much.
SAML isn't suitable for SPA apps as it relays on HTTP POST to transfer data and a need to protect keys on the SPA side.

My recommendation is first to try and use a authentication method better suited to SPA. eg OpenID connect.
If your IdP does not support OpenId connect or you have some requirements that you must use SAML. The best method is to use a identity brokering solution.

When using identity broker, you have a software acting as a translator between OpenID connect used by the SPA and SAML used by the IdP. This way you can use a the OpenID connect standard in SPA but still SAML on your IdP.

Keycloak is a good, free, opensource alternative to use a identity broker.

A few month ago [I wrote a blog post on how to set this up](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/post/saml-for-react-spa/) for a React SPA, ADFS IdP and Keycloak as identity broker. There is a also a automated demo environment in Vagrant and virtual box where you can use to try it out.